# (in C#)How to change the spacing between words and characters

Tags: itext

http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-spacing-between-words-and-characters

Like this in C#,How to do it work?

Comment: This text alignment is called "justify"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
writer.setSpaceCharRatio(PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO);
```

You need this line:

```
writer.SpaceCharRatio = PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO;
```

There are two different mechanisms when converting Java code to C# code:

1. Sometimes you need to change lower-case into upper-case. For instance: `document.add(p);` needs to be changed into `document.Add(p);`
2. Setters in Java are implemented as properties in C#, as is the case with `setSpaceCharRatio` which is used as `SpaceCharRatio`.

Comment: PdfContent=PdfWriter.GetInstance(PdfDocument, PdfStream);
            PdfContent.SpaceCharRatio=PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO;

Comment: It works for me. If it doesn't work for you, you are the only person who can discover why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @aehyok, you need to post actual code and show us what you expected and what you actually got.